# How to make two elements fade after drag and drop is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Codepen for Reference - **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/JBQqdQ)**

I am working on a drag and drop application. After the drop is complete, I've set the draggable to change from red to green, and it fades out.

The droppable, behind the draggable will need to fade out as well. I've tried a few different methods to applying the fade technique to both the draggable and droppable, but I just can't get there.

```js
// Javascript
$(init);

function init() {

  $('#term-1').data( 'number', 1 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+1 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-2').data( 'number', 2 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+2 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-3').data( 'number', 3 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+3 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-4').data( 'number', 4 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+4 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-5').data( 'number', 5 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+5 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-6').data( 'number', 6 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+6 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );


  $('#def-1').data( 'number', 1 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-2').data( 'number', 2 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-3').data( 'number', 3 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-4').data( 'number', 4 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-5').data( 'number', 5 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-6').data( 'number', 6 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

}

var totalCards = $('#cardTerms').children().length;
var totalMatches = 0;

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    totalMatches++;
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'fade' );    
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
  }

  if (totalMatches == totalCards) {
    $('#matchModal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#cardTerms {
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}

#cardDefs {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cardDefs {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#cardTerms {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#cardTerms div, #cardDefs div {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /*border: 1px solid #333;*/
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: .5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
#cardTerms div:first-child, #cardDefs div:first-child {

}
#cardTerms div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}
#cardTerms div {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}
#cardDefs div {
  background: #fff;
  /*border: 1px solid #005575;*/
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
#cardDefs div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

#card1.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card2.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card3.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card4.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card5.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card6.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

.fade {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <!-- HTML here -->
      <div id="content" class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
            <div id="cardTerms">
              <div id="term-1">class</div>
            </div>            
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
            <div id="cardDefs">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" id="def-1">
                  HTML elements can have one or more classes, separated by spaces. You can style elements using CSS by selecting them with their classes.                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The droppable, behind the draggable will fade out as well if you will add `fade class` to it also.

```
$(this).addClass( 'fade' );
```

```js
// Javascript
$(init);

function init() {

  $('#term-1').data( 'number', 1 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+1 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-2').data( 'number', 2 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+2 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-3').data( 'number', 3 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+3 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-4').data( 'number', 4 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+4 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-5').data( 'number', 5 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+5 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );

  $('#term-6').data( 'number', 6 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+6 ).draggable( {
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardTerms div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  } );


  $('#def-1').data( 'number', 1 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-2').data( 'number', 2 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-3').data( 'number', 3 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-4').data( 'number', 4 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-5').data( 'number', 5 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

  $('#def-6').data( 'number', 6 ).droppable( {
    accept: '#cardTerms div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  } );

}

var totalCards = $('#cardTerms').children().length;
var totalMatches = 0;

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );
  //console.log($(this));
  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    totalMatches++;
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'fade' );    
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    $(this).addClass( 'fade' );    
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
  }

  if (totalMatches == totalCards) {
    $('#matchModal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#cardTerms {
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}

#cardDefs {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cardDefs {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#cardTerms {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#cardTerms div, #cardDefs div {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /*border: 1px solid #333;*/
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: .5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
#cardTerms div:first-child, #cardDefs div:first-child {

}
#cardTerms div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}
#cardTerms div {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}
#cardDefs div {
  background: #fff;
  /*border: 1px solid #005575;*/
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
#cardDefs div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

#card1.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card2.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card3.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card4.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card5.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

#card6.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}

.fade {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <!-- HTML here -->
      <div id="content" class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
            <div id="cardTerms">
              <div id="term-1">class</div>
              <div id="term-2">href</div>
              <div id="term-3">body</div>
              <div id="term-4">parent/child</div>
              <div id="term-5">comments</div>
              <div id="term-6">div</div>
            </div>            
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
            <div id="cardDefs">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" id="def-1">
                  HTML elements can have one or more classes, separated by spaces. You can style elements using CSS by selecting them with their classes.                  
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" id="def-2">
                  Links tell the browser where to go using an href attribute, which stores a URL.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">                
                <div class="card-body" id="def-3">
                  The body is the container for all of a page's content. Comes after the <span class="code">&lt;head&gt;</span> tag, within the overall <span class="code">&lt;html&gt;</span> tag.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" id="def-4">
                  An element that is an immediate descendent of another element or nested within another element is called a child. These become useful when using CSS child selectors and psuedo-elements.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" id="def-5">
                  HTML comments are sometimes used in code to explain parts of the markup. They are similar to comments in other languages. Users do not see comments in their browser.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" id="def-6">
                  A block level container (or 'division' of the web page) for content with no semantic meaning.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="matchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Great Work!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Awesome Job! Everything is matched up! Keep up the great work!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Play Again</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All of a sudden, it makes sense. Thanks!